# sendkey to active tmux window

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux session called `test` with several windows, one for each test file. I have another tmux session with vim and the tmuxify plugin. When I tap `<f8>`, my `.vimrc` file is programmed to send the `<f7>` key to the the left pane in window #0 like so:

`nmap <buffer> <F8> :execute "silent !tmux send-keys -t test:0.left 'F7'" <bar>:redraw!<CR>`

`<f7>` triggers the test to be run. Works well.

However, notice the `test:0.left` bit. I have window #0 hardcoded in there. If I want to run the tests in window #7, for example, I first have to swap it with window #0 and then run the test.

What I'd rather do is just send the `<f7>` key to whatever window in the `test` session is currently open.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I consulted ye olde manual. Solution:

`test:.left`

Leaving the window blank defaults to the current window.